# In C#, how can you access a static property of a user-defined type without knowing the type at compiletime?

Tags: c#, static, types

I have some classes that all implement a certain interface. I want to store a unique string in each class that I can get without creating an object for that class. I searched through a lot of posts here already and couldn't find an answer.

If I create an object for each class, then what I want is simply:

```
    class X:IBase{ string m = "x";}

    class Y:IBase{string m = "x";}

    class Z:IBase{string m = "x";}

    class interface IBase{ string m;}

    static int Main(){
      IBase[] arr = {new X(), new Y(), new Z()};
      foreach(IBase b in arr){
          Console.WriteLine(b.m);
      }
    }
```

But I want to do this without creating an object. So I want to do this:

```
    class X:IBase{ static string m = "x";}

    class Y:IBase{ static string m = "x";}

    class Z:IBase{ static string m = "x";}

    class interface IBase{ //no static fields allowed}

    static int Main(){
      Type[] arr = {X, Y, Z};
      foreach(Type t in arr){
          Console.WriteLine(t.m); //error, cannot resolve symbol m
      }
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious or is this just impossible?

The reason I don't want to create an object is because I want to display this string at the start, when I don't need any objects. I only create an object when I need to to save space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reflection is your friend:

```
interface IBase { }
class X : IBase { static string m = "x";}    
class Y : IBase { static string m = "y";}    
class Z : IBase { static string m = "z";}

static void Main()
{
    Type[] arr = { typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z) };
    foreach (Type t in arr)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = t.GetField("m", 
                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        Console.WriteLine(fieldInfo.GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

Note how `Type[] arr = {X, Y, Z};` has been changed into `Type[] arr = { typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z) };` in order to get the `Type` object for each of the types.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I need. I read that reflection should only be used if it's necessary though, since it takes a lot of memory?

Comment: @Yufei: Reflection has a reputation of being a bit slow, but I feel that it is a bit exaggerated. You should avoid it in code that is executed a lot, such as inside a tight loop or so, but for code that runs more seldom, nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Fredrik Thanks for the reply. For some reason it's not working. My type is sent in as a string, and I use `var type = Type.GetType(FullTypeName);` to return the type. Then I do  `FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField("m", BindingFlags.Static);` for property `public static string m = "test";` However, fieldInfo is coming back as null. I am sure type is giving me a valid type when I debug.

Comment: @Yufei: it should be `type.GetField("m", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);` (assuming the field is private as in the original code samples).

Comment: @Fredrik: I changed the variable to public then used the Public flag and it works now thanks a billion! A quick question though. Doesn't the | separating the flags mean or? So why isn't just the Static flag enough?

Comment: @Yufei: yes, | means or, which can be a bit confusing. I have seen that confusion before, so I decided to write a blog post about it: [Using “or” to combine A and B? Explaining that bitmask thing.](http://j.mp/jRFpqe)

Comment: @Fredrik: Nice article! I get why | is used to combine flags, but why must we combine flags? Is just the BindingFlags.Static not enough to return all static variables? Why must we specify public/nonpublic?

Comment: @Yufei: Thanks :-) I obviously misunderstood your confusion though ;-) As I understand it, there are no defaults or assumptions being made for the `BindingFlags` value. The docs say that if you pass zero (which happens to be the value for `BindingFlags.Default`), `null` is returned. So you need to explicitly define each binding flag that you want to match. Otherwise you would need some mechanism to *exclude* settings you don't want (in case you want only non-public fields, for instance).

Answer (score 3):

The obvious thing here is to have `m` be an attribute of an abstract base class and assign a new value in the static constructors of your derivative classes.

You can also use `System.Reflection` for this, if you don't want to go the easy route (abstract base class).

You can also add Attributes to your classes and look up the values there.

Here is the easy route with abstract base classes:

```
abstract class AbstractBase: IBase { protected static string m = "?"; }

class X: AbstractBase { static X() { m = "x"; }}

class Y: AbstractBase { static Y() { m = "y"; }}

class Z: AbstractBase { static Z() { m = "z"; }}

interface IBase { //no static fields allowed}
}

static int Main(){
  AbstractBase[] arr = {new X(), new Y(), new Z()};
  foreach(AbstractBase t in arr){
      Console.WriteLine(t.m); // :)
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I fixed the code sample to remove the compiler errors. Sorry for posting code that wasn't quite right. Doing so, I noticed that the `foreach` loop can't really be done without creating objects, since (unlike python) c# won't let you just refer to a type and call methods on it - that is the job of `System.Reflection`, so, as others have pointed out, you will want to check out `GetMember` and friends.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of that but I really didn't want to make another class, but this was helpful too!

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Thank you for pointing that out. Better drink coffee first and fire up compiler second before I post crap like that again ;) fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Reflection` to access that property....

Like as below ( Example )

```
 MyTypeb = typeof(Myfieldb);
    FieldInfo Myfieldinfob = MyTypeb.GetField("field",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Static);

Console.Write("{0}; ", Myfieldinfoa.GetValue(Myfielda));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Type[] arr = new[] { typeof(X), typeof(Y), typeof(Z) };
foreach(Type t in arr)
{
    FieldInfo fi = t.GetField("m", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    // or PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty(...);
    string m  = (string)fi.GetValue(null);
    // GetValue(null, null);
}
```